# Disappearing components in JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I'm trying to add scroll view in my Swing-UI project. So I've got a JPanel(container) with some JPanels(cards) inside, and I want to put a container in JScrollPane:

```
MealListPanel mlp = new MealListPanel(meals);   
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
scrollPane.setBounds(10,50,1000,400);
scrollPane.setLayout(new ScrollPaneLayout());
scrollPane.add(mlp);
this.add(scrollPane);
```

After that everything is ok, but when I try to scroll, a container disappears:

Before scroll:

[image: Before]

To

[image: After]

What am I doing wrong?

------- Edit ------
Code of MealListView:

`
public class MealListView extends JPanel{

```
private final List<Meal> meals;
public MealListView(List<Meal> meals) {
    this.meals = meals;
    this.configure();
    this.drawMeals();
}

private void configure() {
    this.setBounds(0, 0, 1000, 700);
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 700));
    this.setLayout(null);
}

private void drawMeals()
{   
    System.out.println("Drawing meals");
    int daysCount = 2;
    int mealsCount = 3;

    int columnsCount = 0;               
    int rowsCount = 0;

    int viewWidth = 200;
    int viewHeight = 270;

    for(int index = 0;index < meals.size();index++)
    {           
        MealCardView rp = new MealCardView(meals.get(index));
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle((columnsCount * (10+viewWidth)) + 10,
                 (rowsCount * (10+viewHeight)) + 10,
                 viewWidth, viewHeight);
        rp.setBounds(r);            
        this.add(rp);

        columnsCount++;
        if(columnsCount>=mealsCount-1)
        {
            rowsCount++;
            columnsCount=0;             
        }           
    }

}
```

}

I had to change layout here to null (it was FlowLayout).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `MealListPanel` in [JScrollPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html)'s view port instead of using `scrollPane.add(mlp);`

```
MealListPanel mlp = new MealListPanel(meals);   
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(mlp);
```

You can use [JScrollPane#setViewport()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html#setViewport%28javax.swing.JViewport%29) or `scrollPane.getViewport().add(mlp)` as well.

Comment: Well this worked, but only a little. Now only cards are invisible.

Comment: why are you using `setBounds()` and `setLayout()`?

Comment: share the code that is relevant of `MealListPanel`?

Comment: Well... I'm using AbsoluteLayout in main JPanel, so I have to (?)
set position of scrollPane with `setBounds()`.
`setLayout()` doesn't matter here - `ScrollPanelayout` is set by default. I tried to set layout to null.

Comment: `I'm using AbsoluteLayout in main JPanel,` - Don't! Swing was designed to be used with layout managers.