# Self created graphics disappear when I scroll the image they've been placed on

Tags: java, swing

I am aware that very similars question has been asked before. For example here:
1- [Disappearing components in JScrollPane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24188490/disappearing-components-in-jscrollpane) 
and 2- [Drawing in JPanel disappears when scrolling or ressizing the frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28674876/drawing-in-jpanel-disappears-when-scrolling-or-ressizing-the-frame).

However, I still cannot find the faults in my code. I feel like I've done what the answers suggested there.

What I'm trying to achieve is briefly; I want to chose a file (a png image) from a JFileChoser, then be able to add locations to that map when I click on the map. The location should be pointed out by a triangle. The image is bigger than the Border it is placed in, so it should be scrollable.

I've managed to do all of that, but the problem is the same as in the two above questions - when I scroll on the image, the triangles I've placed on the image disappears. A few outtakes from my code:

```
public PlaceMarker(int xCoordinate, int yCoordinate){
    setBounds(xCoordinate, yCoordinate, 50, 50);
} //This class extends JComponent

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.fillPolygon(xValuesArray, yValuesArray, 3);

    repaint();
}
```

The button where I add the image:

```
JMenuItem newImage = new JMenuItem("New Image");
    newMap.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String directory = System.getProperty("user.dir");
            fileChooser = new JFileChooser(directory);
            int answer = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(MainFrame.this);
            if(answer != JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
                return;
            File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
            String filePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
            if(image != null)
                remove(scrollPane);
            image = new ImageContainer(filePath);
            scrollPane = new JScrollPane(image);
            scrollPane.setMaximumSize(image.getPreferredSize());

            add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            pack();
            validate();
            repaint();
        }
    });
```

I also have this method in my ImageClass:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(image.getImage(), 0, 0, this);
} //This class extends JPanel
```

Comment: It would simplify some things if instead of trying to have `PlaceMarker` extend `JComponent` , you made it a logical class with just coordinates, then painted it directly in the `paintComponent` for your panel (`ImageContainer`?). The downside to that is that it would make some things like tool tips a little more complicated. More to the point at hand, you should try to update your question with a [minimal, complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which reproduces the issue. Also, you need to remove the call to `repaint()` which is inside `PlaceMarker.paintComponent`.

Answer (score 2):

> then be able to add locations to that map when I click on the map.

```
super.paintComponent(g);
g.fillPolygon(xValuesArray, yValuesArray, 3);
```

You only ever paint a single marker. The paintComponent() removes the previous markers.

So you need to keep a List of these custom markers that you want to paint and then iterate through the List to paint all the markers.

Check out the `DrawOnComponent` example found in [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for a working example of this approach.